# Increment fixed value in select clause

Tags: mysql, select

How might one increment a "fixed" value in the `SELECT` clause of a query, so that each row has a different value set? For an **obviously not working** example that illustrates the intention:

```
SELECT
    name, ++x as ordinal
FROM
    foo;

name   | ordinal
----------------
john   | 0
paul   | 1
george | 2
ringo  | 3
```

The ultimate intention is to select users from a database to win first, second, and third prizes. I would have one user win first prize, five second prize winners, and twenty third prize winners:

```
SELECT
    name, IF(++x<2, 'first',  IF(x<7, 'second', 'third') ) as prize
FROM
    foo LIMIT 26;

name     | prize
------------------
alice    | first
bob      | second
charlie  | second
dotan    | second
erik     | second
frank    | second
george   | third
henry    | third
:        | :
:        | :
```

This is running on MySQL v5.5. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [user-defined variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/user-variables.html) for this.

In your first example this would be as simple as this:

```
SELECT
name, @rn := @rn + 1 AS ordinal
FROM
your_table
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := -1) AS var_init_subquery
ORDER BY whatever_column;
```

Here we initialize the variable in another query. This is often more comfortable than doing this:

```
SET @rn := -1;
SELECT
name, @rn := @rn + 1 AS ordinal
FROM
your_table
ORDER BY whatever_column;
```

when you're not allowed to execute multiple statements in PHP or whatever.
The variables are session bound!
Further we initialize it here with `-1` so that the first row will have value `0`, because `@rn + 1` is evaluated first.
Also note, that I added an `ORDER BY` clause. If you don't add it, your result is kind of meaningless, cause there's no order in a relational database unless you specify it. And the calculations done with any variables in the `SELECT` clause rely on the order of the rows.

Regarding your second example, here's just important, to take care of the order in the `SELECT` clause.

```
SELECT
name, @rn := @rn + 1 AS ordinal,
IF(@rn < 2, 'first', IF(@rn < 7, 'second', 'third')) AS prize
FROM
your_table
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := -1) AS var_init_subquery
ORDER BY points DESC; /*or whatever_column*/
```

Comment: This is very useful and I learned much. Thank you!

Comment: EDIT: I don't know why it came to my mind so late^^, but there's no need to assign the `IF(...)` to another variable. Don't know, why I did this in the first place.